# Time Machine "there isn't enough space" despite the backup disk being larger than mine

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, backup, time-machine, catalina

My MacBook Pro is the 250 GB model.

I have a 320 GB external hard drive I am using as a time machine backup disk.

Right now the 320 GB hard drive has 16.14 GB of free space remaining.

The last two backups I tried today both failed because "the disk is full".

I don't see how this can be possible since Time Machine says

> The oldest backups are deleted when your disk becomes full.

How do I force it to backup?

Preferably without wiping the whole disk and making a brand new backup (I don't want to lose all incremental history).

Comment: @klanomath I am scared of the answers on that question bc I assumed time machine kept incremental backups, so deleting the older ones would lose a lot of information

Comment: If the automated TM clean-up doesn't work, you have to do it manually. TM removes the oldest backup(s) first. Deleting the oldest backups manually does exactly the same.

Comment: @klanomath how did I run out of space... `tmutil listbackups` shows only two backups....

Comment: @klanomath wow ffs... `tmutil listbackups` shows 2 backups, so I run `delete` on the volume/computer_name and now it's showing me so many tens of backups being deleted... how come `listbackup` doesn't show these. I would have wanted to delete only the older backups.

Comment: From the linked older q&a: **You can use the tmutil tool to delete backups one by one. `sudo tmutil delete /Volumes/drive_name/Backups.backupdb/mac_name/YYYY-MM-DD-hhmmss`**

Comment: @klanomath to do that I of course need to see what the names of the older backups are, which I tried to lookup using `tmutil listbackups` but see my above comments for the problems I had

Comment: If you check the folder */Volumes/backup_drive_name/Backups.backupdb/mac_name/* with the Finder, you will see all snapshot folders (*YYYY-MM-DD-hhmmss*). If `tmutil listbackups` shows less snapshots something's fundamentally wrong with your TM config/history.